# FreeBSD 9: How to locate an exact filename?

Tags: unix, freebsd, locate

Trying to use `locate` command to find an exact match for the given pattern.
However it results showing all matching files..

For example: I want to find a binary named: **node**

But it gives me all matches containing this word:

```
server2# locate node
/usr/share/man/man9/getnewvnode.9.gz
/usr/share/man/man9/ieee80211_amrr_node_init.9.gz
/usr/share/man/man9/ieee80211_dump_node.9.gz
/usr/share/man/man9/ieee80211_dump_nodes.9.gz
/usr/share/man/man9/ieee80211_find_rxnode.9.gz
/usr/share/man/man9/ieee80211_find_rxnode_withkey.9.gz
/usr/share/man/man9/ieee80211_free_node.9.gz
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at `locate --help`, you may find:

```
  -r, --regexp REGEXP    search for basic regexp REGEXP instead of patterns
      --regex            patterns are extended regexps
```

You can use `-r` to provide a regexp pattern to `locate`:

```
locate -r /node$
```

The `/` ensures `node` is at the start of the file name. The `$` ensures `node` is at the end of the file name. This will give you *only* the files matching the exact file name.

If you want to do a case-insensitive search (matches `Node`, `NODE`, `nOdE`, etc), add `-i`:

```
locate -i -r /node$
```

If locate does not support regexp, you can use grep (as mentioned by Iracicot):

```
locate node | grep /node$
locate -i node | grep -i /node$
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `-b` switch to only match against the basename: `locate -br node$`

Answer (score 6):

You may use grep with locate

```
server2# locate node | grep node$
```

The $ sign will tell grep to look at the end of the string.

Comment: Result is the same. It brings up different matches ending with node... /usr/ports/www/p5-WebService-Linode. I guess it should be /node$ ?

Comment: Yes you can try this too (But I'm not sure if the / character must be escaped or not). Have you tried locate -b ?

Answer (score 0):

Disable `locate`'s implicit glob by adding your own glob that matches all directories:

```
locate */node
```

From the man page:

> If any `PATTERN` contains no globbing characters, locate behaves as if the pattern were `*PATTERN*`

This syntax will match a complete file or directory name anywhere, including in the root.